# append two data frame with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to merge two dataframes by rows doing:

```
bigdata = data1.append(data2)
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Exception: Index cannot contain duplicate values!
> ```

The index of the first data frame starts from 0 to 38 and the second one from 0 to 48. I didn't understand that I have to modify the index of one of the data frame before merging, but I don't know how to.

Thank you.

These are the two dataframes:

`data1`:

```
    meta  particle  ratio   area    type    
0   2     part10    1.348   0.8365  touching
1   2     part18    1.558   0.8244  single  
2   2     part2     1.893   0.894   single  
3   2     part37    0.6695  1.005   single  
....clip...
36  2     part23    1.051   0.8781  single  
37  2     part3     80.54   0.9714  nuclei  
38  2     part34    1.071   0.9337  single
```

`data2`:

```
    meta  particle  ratio    area    type    
0   3     part10    0.4756   1.025   single  
1   3     part18    0.04387  1.232   dusts   
2   3     part2     1.132    0.8927  single  
...clip...
46  3     part46    13.71    1.001   nuclei  
47  3     part3     0.7439   0.9038  single  
48  3     part34    0.4349   0.9956  single
```

the first column is the index

Comment: Could you please post snapshots of both `dataframe` objects (i.e. in the python interpreter, type in the name of the `dataframe` so the objects are enumerated on the screen).  Also post what keywords you used when you performed the merge.  As you can see http://pandas.sourceforge.net/dataframe.html, there are a few ways to combine dataframes... make sure you're using the one that makes the most sense for what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: here's a print of the two dataframes:

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see the contents of `data1` and `data2` in this web page... please edit them into the original question

Comment: sorry I don't handle very well the presentation

Comment: the dataframe are here [https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-YDFMbEy1grYzc1ZWIyZGItMTY2Yi00YjIzLTk1NDktYWFjMTE0NTI2OGJj&hl=fr]

Comment: it's no problem... I helped with the formatting.  Thank you for sharing the details... could you elaborate on how you will use `bigdata` after you have appended the `DataFrame` objects.  Knowing this will help me understand which way the data should be combined

Comment: I plan to do a [scatter plot](http://dip4fish.blogspot.com/2011/10/chromosomes-overlapping-chromosomes-and.html) with more points

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `append` function has an optional argument `ignore_index` which you should use here to join the records together, since the index isn't meaningful for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You could first identify the index-duplicated (not value) row using `groupby` method, and then do a sum/mean operation on all the rows with the duplicate index.

```
data1 = data1.groupby(data1.index).sum()
data2 = data2.groupby(data2.index).sum()
```

Comment: I had dupes with panel = panel1.append(panel2). And then this removed them: panel = panel.groupby(panel.index).sum()  So thx. (I'm told I'm working with panels, not dataframes, how to know)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.concat`

```
bigdata = pd.concat([data1,data2])
```